# Use individual dynamic field value with update_all in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

I have two fields namely `cost` and `var_cost` both of type `Integer`, User can enter a number in the text field, on submit the number will be updated for the `cost` field for multiple records, but `var_cost` of the individual record should be added to the number before assigning it to the `cost` field.

```
Variation.where(conditions).update_all(cost: number + var_cost)
```

I have tried this but it is not working, is there a way to use `var_cost` of individual record with `update_all`, any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The duplicate question doesn't have solution to the question I asked, please reopen

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3974985/479863 though. I think you're stuck doing it by hand document by document. You can send some JavaScript into MongoDB to do a `forEach` on the collection but it'll still be nasty. Mongoid isn't going to be able to let you do things that MongoDB doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

The problem your having above is that rails is interpreting both number and var_cost.  You want number to be interpreted by rails, and var_cost to be interpreted by your database.

Variation.where(conditions).update_all("cost = var_cost + #{number.to_i}")

Be sure if you don't do number.to_i that you sanitize it.